# Self-hosted OWIN OAuth2 on mono 4 returns 500 Internal Server Error on oauth2/token route

Tags: .net, oauth, mono, owin, jwt

I am trying to implement a (self-hosted) OAuth2 authorization server using OWIN and the OAuth2 middleware with JSON Web Tokens that will have to run on mono - basically following [this](http://bitoftech.net/2014/10/27/json-web-token-asp-net-web-api-2-jwt-owin-authorization-server/) blog post - so far without success. I tried using the `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth` approach as well as IdentityServer3, which are **failing to serve tokens with mono 4 on both Windows and Linux** (the latter using the `mono:onbuild` docker image). When started using the .NET runtime, everything works as expected.

Now I'm really wondering if I forgot something very simple (because nobody else seems to have that problem on the web) or if there really is something buggy going on.

### The Problem

While WebAPI routes *do* work on both .NET 4.5 and mono 4, any access to the configured `oauth2/token` endpoint silently fails with an `500 Internal Server Error`, that is without a body and without any error information whatsoever. As for IdentityServer running the [minimal self-hosted](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/f2a3225110e50b92f18d3b60a47d90ae519e7d94/source/SelfHost%20(Minimal)) example, the HTTPS endpoint doesn't even *accept* connections when running on mono. When instead configured to allow HTTP, it first fails with a silent `500` as above (the very same error it seems), then on a second call basically explodes with a "not initialized" exception on every access.

In general, the response is simply

```
StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
Server: Mono-HTTPAPI/1.0
Date: Thu, 03 Sep 2015 22:32:58 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 0
}
```

### Full Code

I uploaded the full source to GitHub [here](https://github.com/sunsided/web-owin-webapi-oauth/tree/so-question) for the OAuth2 middleware (the `auth` project) and [here](https://github.com/sunsided/web-owin-webapi-oauth/tree/so-question-is3) for the IdentityServer3 approach (the `is3` project, which I did downgrade to a stable NuGet package; it's on prerelease in the sample linked above - it doesn't change anything though). On Linux, both are built with the docker shell scripts (the build one, then run one). On Windows, they are built with Visual Studio 2015 against .NET 4.5 and then run using mono 4.0.

### What I did

The `Startup` configuration is baseline as described in the [blog post](http://bitoftech.net/2014/10/27/json-web-token-asp-net-web-api-2-jwt-owin-authorization-server/),

```
public void Configuration([NotNull] IAppBuilder appBuilder)
{
      var config = new HttpConfiguration();

      var encryptionKey = "my super secret encryption key";
      appBuilder.UseAesDataProtectorProvider(encryptionKey);

      config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

      appBuilder.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
      ConfigureOAuth(appBuilder);

      appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
}

public void ConfigureOAuth([NotNull] IAppBuilder appBuilder)
{
      var serverOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
      {
            ApplicationCanDisplayErrors = true,
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/oauth2/authorize"),
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/oauth2/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            Provider = new CustomOAuthProvider(),
            AccessTokenFormat = new CustomJwtFormat("foobar")
      };

      appBuilder.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(serverOptions);
}
```

where the `UseAesDataProtectorProvider()` call is used to replace the default DPAPI which doesn't exist on Linux.

In the `CustomOAuthProvider`, the `ValidateClientAuthentication()` method is simply fetching credentials using

```
string clientId;
string clientSecret;
if (!context.TryGetBasicCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret))
{
      context.TryGetFormCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret);
}
```

and then eventually calling either `context.Validated()` or `context.Rejected()`. This call succeeds on both .NET and mono.

In `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials()`, the ticket is eventually created using

```
  var identity = new ClaimsIdentity("JWT");

  identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName));
  identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));

  identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Manager"));
  identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Supervisor"));

  var props = new AuthenticationProperties(
        new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
                {
                     "audience", context.ClientId ?? string.Empty asserten!
                }
        });

  var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, props);
  context.Validated(ticket);
```

This call succeeds as well on both .NET and mono.

### What I found

By placing `Console.WriteLines(...)` all over the class, I managed to track down the problem to happen between `CustomOAuthProvider.TokenEndpoint()` and `CustomOAuthProvider.TokenEndpointResponse()`, where the latter one is only ever entered on .NET.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Having the same problem with an XSP hosted app. The exception thrown and displayed in the browser on attempting to POST to the token endpoind is somehow self explanatory and points to line 98 in DefaultHttpHandler.cs :(https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/25354134/) "Method POST not allowed for accessing file 'token'. Why the token request is handled like an ordinary static file request, is beyond my knowledge. It seems to me, that big parts of Mono are not up-to-date enough to keep up with .net.

Comment: Hum, bit of a stretch, but could that be an issue with the ordering of the modules, e.g. `app.UseStaticFiles()` before `app.UseOAuthSomething()`? In my case, there isn't even an exception, regardless of `POST`ing or `GET`ing ... sneaky one, that error.

Comment: I'm not even calling UseStaticFiles, strangely enough it is not even offered me as an API call in Xamarin Studio's Intellisense and if I enter it I'm getting an error (Owin.IAppBuilder does not contain a definition for UseStaticFiles....) EDIT: Maybe it is because I haven't added Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles at all

Comment: @decades, I'm probably switching to ASP.NET 5. I had a quick test on Linux using their provided Docker image and from what I can tell, everything works just fine. Except that it's beta, there's no documentation and everything is different. Whoop!

Comment: thanks for the follow up. Working on a MAC. Right now to have it running in Xamarin/Mono is just nice to have, so I doubt that I will mess with ASP.NET 5 at this early stage here. Will stick with Windows/VisualStudio 2015 so far. Thanks for letting me know, nevertheless.